# Authorize.net AIM error. Payment will still proceed even if it's supplied with an invalid billing address

Tags: php, web, e-commerce, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I've tried to update the AVS settings and decline all transactions without or invalid billing address.
I'm trying to fix this issue but still cant figure it out.

Here is my current AVS Settings.

[image]

Please take a look at my code and see if there's wrong with it.

```
$post_url = "https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll";          
        $CC_API   = "*****";
        $CC_KEY   = "*****";


        $amount = number_format($formData[total_amt],2);


                  $post_values = array(

                    // the API Login ID and Transaction Key must be replaced with valid values
                    "x_login"           => $CC_API,
                    "x_tran_key"            => $CC_KEY,
                    "x_version"         => "3.1",
                    "x_delim_data"          => "TRUE",
                    "x_delim_char"          => "|",
                    "x_relay_response"      => "FALSE",

                    "x_type"            => "AUTH_ONLY",
                    "x_method"          => "CC",
                    "x_card_num"            => $formData[cc_num],
                    "x_exp_date"            => $formData[cc_expM].$formData[cc_expY],

                    "x_amount"          =>  $amount ,
                    "x_description"         => "Test Order",

                    "x_first_name"          => $formData[cc_fname],
                    "x_last_name"           => $formData[cc_lname],
                    "x_company"         => $Data[cust_bill_company_name],
                    "x_address"         => $Data[cust_bill_street_address],
                    "x_city"                        => $Data[cust_bill_city],
                    "x_state"                       => $Data[cust_bill_state],
                    "x_zip"                         => $Data[cust_bill_postcode],
                    "x_country"                     => $Data[cust_bill_country],
                    "x_email"                       => $Data[cust_email],

                          //shipping
                    "x_ship_to_first_name"  => $Data[cust_ship_fname],
                    "x_ship_to_last_name"   => $Data[cust_ship_lname],
                    "x_ship_to_company"     => $Data[cust_ship_company_name],
                    "x_ship_to_address"     => $Data[cust_ship_street_address],
                    "x_ship_to_city"        => $Data[cust_ship_city],
                    "x_ship_to_state"       => $Data[cust_ship_state],
                    "x_ship_to_zip"         => $Data[cust_ship_zip],
                    "x_ship_to_country"     => $Data[cust_ship_country]


                  );

                  // This section takes the input fields and converts them to the proper format
                  // for an http post.  For example: "x_login=username&x_tran_key=a1B2c3D4"
                  $post_string = "";
                  foreach( $post_values as $key => $value )
                    { $post_string .= "$key=" . urlencode( $value ) . "&"; }
                  $post_string = rtrim( $post_string, "& " );

                  // This sample code uses the CURL library for php to establish a connection,
                  // submit the post, and record the response.
                  // If you receive an error, you may want to ensure that you have the curl
                  // library enabled in your php configuration
                  $request = curl_init($post_url); // initiate curl object
                    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // set to 0 to eliminate header info from response
                    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // Returns response data instead of TRUE(1)
                    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string); // use HTTP POST to send form data
                    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); // uncomment this line if you get no gateway response.
                    $post_response = curl_exec($request); // execute curl post and store results in $post_response
                    // additional options may be required depending upon your server configuration
                    // you can find documentation on curl options at http://www.php.net/curl_setopt
                    curl_close ($request); // close curl object

                    // This line takes the response and breaks it into an array using the specified delimiting character
                    $response_array = explode($post_values["x_delim_char"],$post_response);

        return ($response_array[0]=="1" && $response_array[1]=="1") ? "ok" : $response_array[3];
```

Comment: Are you in the production environment? Or using the developer server?

Comment: Yes we're using the production environment.

Comment: what will happen if we're using the developer server ?

Comment: Your code above is pointing to the sandbox, not production.  The sandbox only simulates a connection to the payment processor.  To generate specific error conditions, you'll need to use the error generation guide at http://developer.authorize.net/tools/errorgenerationguide/

Comment: Originally the code above is pointing to the production merchant account not the sandbox account. I have decided to use the sandbox for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The sandbox only simulates a connection to the payment processor. To generate specific error conditions, you'll need to use the error generation guide at http://developer.authorize.net/tools/errorgenerationguide